# As i have read local variable declared in side a func gets destroyed once the func finishes execution. Then how This code is working

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(int **p)
{
 int j=2;
 *p=&j;
 printf("%d  \n",**p );

}
int main()
{
 int i=97 ;
 int *p=&i;
 foo(&p);
 printf("%d \n",*p );
 return 0;
}
```

**According to definition :A local variable is destroyed at the moment that the program execution reaches the end of the method in which the local variable is defined**
Then how in main() func it is still able to print 2. If int j=2; is already destroyed?
**Is it like the variables gets destroyed but it is still accessible by addresses?I know this is call by reference**

Comment: You have passed the address of `p` as a parameter to `foo`. In foo, the pointer is set to the address of `j` and the value (2)` is printed before return. Now back in `main()` the fun begins. There `p` is a *Dangling-Pointer* because the address it holds is to an object that no longer exists. Attempts to access values at that address results in *Undefined Behavior* (your code could continue to appear to work, or SegFault, or anything in between)

Comment: Variables aren't "destroyed". In order to understand this fully, you must simply realize that computer programs either keep track of the contents of a RAM cell or they don't. In case they don't, they just let whatever value that happened to be in the cell be - it no longer cares about the memory cell. The linked duplicate has a nice analogy for it all.

Comment: Additionally, see [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486) where I picked this very scenario as one of the examples.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks a lot. Got it now.

Comment: @Lundin Yep checked out that link thanks for the response.

Comment: @Lundin: Note that the duplicate you linked to is C++, not C. However, it is such a good analogy that I think that it was still worth linking to it. The only thing a C programmer must know to understand the question is that `std::cout` is equivalent to `printf`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel We use that one as canonical dupe for this C FAQ question too. It's better than to dig up some other random question.